# how to make paramiko wait until for custom prompt appears?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a linux based custom box, which has a banner kind of thing (i am not sure wether its a banner either) which appears on login and then the custom prompt, with paramiko sshclient.connect() the script comes out of the ssh session even before the custom prompt comes up , is there any way to wait until the custom prompt appears and then run the execute command ?

the banner is like this

```
Command Line Interface is starting up, please wait ...

   Welcome to the Platform Command Line Interface

VMware Installation:
        2 vCPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v2 @ 3.00GHz
        Disk 1: 146GB, Partitions aligned
        10240 Mbytes RAM

admin:
```

paramiko exits the ssh session once "Command Line Interface is starting up, please wait ..." line comes up

Comment: is there any other alternative to paramiko in python which would help resolve this  ?

Comment: Does it exit with any particular error? Can you provide it?

Comment: No error , it just simply exits . i tried searching paramiko docs to see if any debug mode is available . but there seems to be none.

Comment: Paramiko uses standard python logging, set up logger in debug mode, and you will see all details.